# Migrating JDO based App Engine app to Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I would like to migrate my JDO based App Engine app to objectify. But It would be quite a lot of work to do this as there are a lot of queries.

Is it possible to use JDO and Objectify side by side, using the same entity classes somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest version of Objectify (I'm using Objectify v4 at the time of writing), it is possible to use JDO and Objectify and annotate the same classes with no problems in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [Objectify Link](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_do_I_migrate_from_JDO_to_Objectify?) to migrate from JDO to Objectify.

Comment: I've seen this already, but it doesn't explain a way to use the same entity classes with JDO and Objectify side by side.